# Connect via DHCP via LAN cable between a Windows and Linux device

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, dhcp

I am working with DHCP IP addresses. When I connect my device to a server, the server generates an IP address that it then assigns to my device. Which is great! I am trying to connect my PC to my linux device via DHCP (I know. Why?). When I change my /etc/network/interfaces file and add `auto eth0 iface eth0 inet dhcp` and restart the network and have my linux device connected to my computer (my Windows computer is configured to automatic IPv4), it does not generate an IP address. I want the PC to be the "server" and assign my linux device an IP address that it can then connect to (usually starts with 169.254.x.x). I want this to be automatic and not where I have to go back and change it manually. Is there something I have to change in any configuration files for my linux device to have a DHCP IP address when it is connected via lan cable? I know I can just use static to connect two devices, but I also want this to work for a specific application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This only works if your Windows PC acts as a DHCP Server (which means you would need to install a DHCP service on the PC). The 169.254... IPs are APIPA adresses, and while they might work between two Windows machines, they probably won't with Linux.

I would suggest one of the following options:

1) Assign static IP adresses (would be the easiest).

2) Install a DHCP server on *one* of the two machines (e.g. dhcpd on Linux). Be aware though that without proper configuration that PC will probably have problems once you connect it to, say, your DHCP-enabled home router (so you might have to turn the server back off in that case).

3) Enable IPv6 on both machines. IPv6 has a proper way of auto-assigning IP adresses, which actually work ;)

Tobi

Comment: Thanks! Perfect answer. I'm just going to assign a static address that starts with "169.254.x.x" and check for address conflicts in my code.

Comment: I'd suggest you assign them a proper private IPv4 address, for good practice and to avoid trouble. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network